# How to close floating context menu programatically?

Tags: android, menu

How do you close a context menu programatically? (such as the one seen [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu)).

I have searched the documents and tried google how to close context menus, but the term menu is bringing up too many results for me to be able to narrow down my search.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you overridden and tried the `onContextItemSelected` method?

Answer (score 1):

try this will help you :

```
((Activity) mContext).closeContextMenu();
```